# How do you add a custom link to the wordpress login page?

Tags: wp-login-form

http://redrokk.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/blank_wordpress_login_form1.png

I want to add a custom link before the 'Lost your password?' link. I'm currently using a function that has some css to style my wordpress login page(I don't have a separate page for the login page). Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can add link after lost your password, but I don't think you can add link before lost your password link unless you design your own login page.

```
function hook_lost_your_password ( $text ) {
        if ($text == 'Lost your password?'){
            $text .= '<br /><a href="http://codebing.com">Visit Code Bing</a>';
        }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'hook_lost_your_password' );
```

Source ([Code Bing](http://codebing.com))

Answer (score 1):

There are few login form hooks which could be useful to you:

```
login_form AND login_footer
```

You can find more information about them in the Codex: [Customizing_the_Login_Form#Login_Hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Login_Hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clean url` filter to add the new link in an evil way.

```
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'wpse_99251_add_anchor_to_login_form', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Add an anchor (link) to the login form.
 */
function wpse_99251_add_anchor_to_login_form( $good_protocol_url, $original_url ) {

    // Check to see if we are on the login page and escaping the "Lost Password?" url.
    if ( 'wp-login.php' == $GLOBALS['pagenow'] && $original_url == wp_lostpassword_url() ) {

        // If we get here, we are inside the href atribute of the lost password anchor.
        // So, the anchor we add starts in its middle.
        return sprintf(
            '%s" title="%s">%s</a> | <a href="%s',
            esc_url( 'https://my_link' ),           // Change to your link url.
            esc_attr( 'My Link Title' ),            // Change to your link title.
            'My Link Name',                         // change to your link name.
            $good_protocol_url
        );
    }

    return $good_protocol_url;
}
```